# I deleted my .htaccess. easy way to fix this?

Tags: users, .htaccess

I'm clueless enough that I managed to delete my .htaccess file from my drupal site (after some mistaked advice from my webhost tech support).
Now, I can go to the home page, but links to all internal pages result in 404 not found.
I'm using drupal 5 and my web host is dreamhost.
I don't have a recent backup of my site. I did find a very old htaccess file, and uploaded it, but then it threw a login pass popup.

Is there an easy way to fix this? Must I have the htaccess file?
How can I generate a new one that will work with my site?

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go the . htaccess for drupal 5.x

http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/refs/heads/5.x:/.htaccess

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any modification from the original file then you're ok the just upload this `.htaccess` from [Drupal 5 repository](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/refs/heads/5.x:/.htaccess).

It throws 404 because there is something in your clean url settings that depends in `.htaccess`, thats the reason why your URL rewrite is not working.

I advice to always backup before touching anything in your production environment so you can roll it back when something goes wrong.

Comment: Without the .htaccess file, any link like http://example.com/node/1 raises a 404 error because it is Drupal .htaccess that change those links to http://example.com/index.php?q=node/1.